# Wildfly 11 maven web application context name

Tags: java, wildfly-10

I'm trying to deploy a maven application called `news` to Wildfly 10.1 from Eclipse. It is a maven web application. The deployment works fine, but the context path is `news-SNAPSHOT-0.0.1` while I need `news`.
Any idea? I've tried everything in `pom.xml`..

Comment: Can you add your pom.xml?

Comment: thank you, will add code a bit later

Comment: WildFly 11, already?